# finding terms in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

Consider the equation

$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}}+y\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}=\Gamma \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial{x}^2}$

where $\Gamma$ is a constant term.

Given that $y=\frac{y_0}{2}-\frac{y_0}{2}tanh(\frac{x-ct}{L})$  satisfies the equation above, find $L$ and $c$ in terms of the constants $y_0$ or $\Gamma$

My attempt:

$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{-y_0}{2L}sech^2(\Phi)$  where $\Phi=\frac{x-ct}{L}$.

$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}}=\frac{y_0c}{2L}sech^2(\Phi)$

$\frac{\partial^2{y}}{\partial{x}^2}=\frac{y_0}{L^2}sech^2(\Phi)tanh(\Phi)$

Hence plugging them into the equation above we get

$1-\frac{y}{c}=\Gamma \frac{2}{cL}tanh(\Phi)$, so $1-\frac{y_0}{2c}=\frac{4\Gamma-y_0L}{2cL}tanh(\Phi)$

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1-\frac{y_0}{2c}=\frac{4\Gamma-y_0L}{2cL}\tanh(\Phi)$$
must hold for any $t,x$ so must be
$$
\begin{cases}
1-\frac{y_0}{2c}=0\\
4\Gamma-y_0L=0\\
\end{cases}$$
Solution is $\left(L= \frac{4 \Gamma}{y_0},c= \frac{y_0}{2}\right)$

Comment: thanks! this makes sense